# Add column from one dataframe to muliheader dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In the following code how to merge the df2 to df3 to get an output like `df4`. df3 is a multiheader dataframe and in the final ouput i just need the first level of the header as show.how to achieve this

```
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Maths':[95,96,97,98] ,'Science': [91,92,93,94]})
    >>> df2=pd.DataFrame({'Languages': ['English','Hindi','French','Spanish']})

    >>> header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Subjects'],['Maths', 'Science']])
    >>> df3 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.tolist(), columns=header)
    >>> df3
      Subjects        
         Maths Science
    0       95      91
    1       96      92
    2       97      93
    3       98      94

    >>> df2
    Languages
    0   English
    1     Hindi
    2    French
    3   Spanish
```

`Output df4`

```
    Subjects               Languages
         Maths Science
    0       95      91      English
    1       96      92      Hindi
    2       97      93      French
    3       98      94      Spanish
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firat add `MultiIndex` to `df2` and then `concat` or `join`:

```
df2.columns = [df2.columns, ['']]
#another solution
#df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2.columns, ['']])
df4 = pd.concat([df3, df2], axis =1)
#another solution
#df4 = df3.join(df2)
```

---

```
print (df4)
  Subjects         Languages
     Maths Science          
0       95      91   English
1       96      92     Hindi
2       97      93    French
3       98      94   Spanish
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df4 = pd.concat([df3, df2], axis =1)
```

Comment: Nope this would not give me the expected output, >>> df4
   (Subjects, Maths)  (Subjects, Science) Languages
0                 95                   91   English
1                 96                   92     Hindi
2                 97                   93    French
3                 98                   94   Spanish

Comment: Do you try it? for me it break `MultiIndex`